# Find statistical data for every combination(Uncommon one) of data using PHP & Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, statistics

[image: Example of Data]

In this example, I want average smoke column for every combination. Here when thing get complicate.

It's **NOT** simple as find average(smoke) of (Male,30-40,us),(Male,30-40,ca),(Male,30-40,th) and so on.

What I want is some variable can use for more than 1 times in a single query like (Male,30-40,(us,uk)) ,(Male,30-40,(us,uk,th)) ,,(Male,30-40,(us,uk,th,ca)) and more.

Any simple,efficient way to do?

Comment: can't you just write a report generator where the user selects the conditionals and then you build that into a where clause so you'd then do something like `select avg(smoke) from tbldetails where gender='Male' AND (age='30-40' OR age='50-60') AND Country IN('us','ca','th')`

Comment: I want every possible combination. Data can grow larger than this. Maybe 300,000 people on 100+ new different country and 10 age_range. the script and query need to be dynamics.

Comment: if you want to automate it to bring back all possible solutions you'll have to either normalise into key tables and link those tables to entries in your data table or you'd have to multiple loop through your single table first to get all distincs for stuff like sex, age, etc

Answer (score 0):

If you can, I would suggest normalizing your data so that it is easier to use the built in functions to achieve your goal.  That is probably going to be faster than coming up with a query that will work with the way you have it now.

Comment: please explain more. After database normalization, Do you have any suggestion on how to write php and/or mysql query?

Answer (score 0):

You can get every combination like this:

```
SELECT q.sort_key,avg(s.id)
FROM foo AS s
JOIN
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(f0.bar) AS sort_key
   FROM foo AS f1
   JOIN foo AS f2 ON f1.bar<=f2.bar
   JOIN foo AS f3 ON f2.bar<=f3.bar
   JOIN foo AS f0 ON f0.bar=f1.bar OR f0.bar=f2.bar OR f0.bar=f3.bar
   GROUP BY f1.bar,f2.bar,f3.bar) AS q ON find_in_set(s.bar,q.sort_key)
GROUP BY q.sort_key;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1fdbf/32

Since MySQL doesn't support recursive CTE you will have to use as many tables as there can be diffrent values of that parameter (2 for gender, 4(?) for country and so on). Once you have the possible combination on all parameters do a cartesian join on them and group by them. In PHP you will just have to change a sort key like (male,female) to ALL GENDERS.

EDIT2:
Fixed the dupes, probably joins could be better but it still works like it should.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to concatenate the independent / predictor variables as a string in a separate column, then get AVG(smoke) based on a GROUP BY of the string

```
ALTER TABLE `statistical_data` ADD `variables_string` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL 

UPDATE `statistical_data` SET`variables_string` = CONCAT(`gender`, `age`, `country`)

SELECT `gender`, `age`, `country`, AVG(smoke) FROM `statistical_data`GROUP BY `variables_string`
```

A WHERE clause can be used, for example, to get an average of all combinations WHERE sex is male, but you have to divide the sum of smoke (number of 1's) for all combinations by the frequency of combinations (n), because you can't take an average of averages.

```
SELECT (SUM(smoke_sum) / SUM(smoke_count)) FROM (SELECT `gender`, `age`, `country`, SUM(smoke) AS smoke_sum, COUNT(smoke) AS smoke_count FROM`statistical_data` WHERE `gender` = 'male' GROUP BY variables_string ) AS t2
```

Comment: You don't need a new column for that, you can just do `GROUP BY gender,age,country` and the result will be exactly the same. And that won't give you every posible combination. Also you're selecting a name (in *) you didn't group by so your result will be unpredictable.

Comment: I'm thinking a separate column will perform better on larger data. Also, the result will not be unpredictable because the name variable is presumably not needed in the analysis, so the random name thrown out can be ignored. Yes, this will give every possible combination, because each combination of gender, age and country will have a unique string.

Comment: It will give you average for males, 30-40, us but will not give you a result for males, all ages, all countries. And if you know name will be semirandom you shouldn't select it, it's just garbage.

Comment: It will give you an average for each and all combinations. I've edited my answer to explain how to include a WHERE clause, with an example of how to select males, all ages, all countries. It's a pedantic, but fair point about the garbage (also edited).